# Moved folder into other has now disappeared

Tags: directory

I had two folders in the same directory and I wanted to move one into other with the command `mv foo /foo2`. But now `foo` has vanished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the above command terminated without a `Permission Denied` error, it means you had root privileges when you ran it and it actually moved the directory `foo` into the directory `/foo2`, which is *not* `foo2` in the current directory, but `foo2` under the root directory (`/`).

You'll want to do

```
mv /foo2 foo2
```

in the directory where you issued the original command.

Comment: yep just found it - i forgot it would end up in /